# Why vector3 needs more arguments

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to make an endless game from youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTTBbXYH9BA&t=585s. In the video, the code is working properly. But in my Visual Studio, it saying "Vector3 does not contain a constructor that takes four arguments".

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private bool ismovingright = false;
    [SerializeField]
    float speed = 4f;
    void Start () 
    {
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();    
    }

    private Rigidbody rb;

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            ChangeBoolean();
            ChangeDirection();
        }
    }

    private void ChangeBoolean()
    {
        ismovingright = !ismovingright;
    }

    private void ChangeDirection()
    {
        if (ismovingright)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0f, 0f,);

        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0f, 0f, speed);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, there is an additional comma after 0f

```
if (ismovingright)
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0f, 0f,);
}else
```

Comment: Still, there is no movement in the ball. As in the video.

Comment: Than check the speed in the Unity inspector / is the Rigidbody enabled? Is using gravity or kinematic .....?